# how to register Com component in WinCE 5.0?

Tags: c++, windows-ce, exe

I have created a COM Component in C++. Now i want to register my COM Component in WinCE 5.0 and use it in ASP(.asp) pages by calling ActiveXObject();. Please help me in registering the COM component.

Comment: Is the windows CE running on Intel or another architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be utility called regsvrce.exe , just google for it or follow link at bottom.

But you can create simple installation utility like described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsmobiledev/thread/3f056507-3f2a-470d-bf51-7a8230f56f47)

Also Look [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=305513) and [here](http://www.ivcdisplays.com/faq.htm)